# Django object model - dynamically setting value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How do I dynamically set the values of a Django object model by iterating through the parameters in the request GET.

So get the field name and values from the request object and use that to iterate throw and update the Django model with the respective fields.

```
user = request.GET.get('user')
name = request.GET.get('name')
created = request.GET.get('created')
modified = request.GET.get('modified')

obj, created = Obj.objects.get_or_create(user=user, name=name)

if created:

    obj.created = created
    obj.modified = modified

    obj.save(update_fields=['created', 'modified'])
```

Comment: use a model form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is generally achieved through a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) it allows you to map request parameters to a model instance and validate those parameters, then optionally save/update the instance.

Using a form is probably the safest way, and def best practice, but there's no reason you can't dynamically iterate over the `request.GET`

```
for k, v in request.GET.items():
  setattr(obj, k, v)

obj.save(update_fields=[request.GET.keys()])
```

This is missing a check that the `k` is an actual property of `Obj`.   type assertions should take place on save, but the form workflow allows for a uniform standardized ways to detect type errors and present them to the client when the occur.